# Passing CLLocationCoordinate2D Array as return type

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocation

Hi have a method which has to return CLLocationCoordinate2D array. Is there a way to do this?

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[count];
I wanna return coordinates;

I don't want to put this on array and send as NSArray, Just want to send as CLLocationCoordinate2D array.

Comment: I got the solution for this myself.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer.

Comment: Hi, @picciano I have posted the answer which I used before 2yrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Set -

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D cooArray[5];
    cooArray[0] = _locationCoo1;
    cooArray[1] = _locationCoo2;
    cooArray[2] = _locationCoo3;
    cooArray[3] = _locationCoo4;
```

To Get -

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location1 = cooArray[0];
```

To get Size of Array

```
 NSLog(@" :%lu", sizeof(cooArray));
```